# Can you compare which source DataGridView comes from?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm a beginner in Visual Basic and I'm writing this code wherein the source of a DataGridView (can be table or query) can be changed through a button click. I'm currently working with an Access database and I was just wondering if there is any way to compare the sources. I'm comparing the sources since I have to filter the DataGridView with a DateTimePicker and the columns for the dates have different field names.

I have thought of doing this code but it doesn't work:

```
If DataGridView1.DataSource = CstmrOrder_Query Then 
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select *  from CstmrOrder_Query where OrderDateTime Between #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "# and #" & DateTimePicker3.Value.Date & "#", conn)
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
Else If DataGridView1.DataSource = SuppliesStocks
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select *  from SuppliesStocks where StockInDateTime Between #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "# and #" & DateTimePicker3.Value.Date & "#", conn)
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

I tried it once and the error says: Operator '=' is not defined for type DataTable and type 'CstmrOrder_QueryDataTable'.

Is there any alternative to do this or I'm just simply doing it wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your DataGridView Control already has a DataSource set. Are you trying to filter the data, or this actually needs to be a different query, that replaces the current data entirely? -- `DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).TableName` gives you the name of the Table. If the date/time Column is unique, in a specific ordinal position or the first of the same type, you don't need to map the Table name to a Column name

Comment: You should avoid this kind of stuff: `... Between #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "# and #" & ...`  and use Command Parameters instead -- You should also avoid, especially with an Access db, storing the Connection and Command objects. Declare them locally, with Using statements (very important).

Comment: I was trying to have several tables be shown in one DataGridView via buttons and also displayed the filtered data in the same DataGridView, but I realized after posting this that I could've done it differently by using different DataGridView for each table/query and just show/hide it. I'll take note of using the command parameters. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work around this. Instead of trying to compare sources, I tried creating several DataGridView and placed them on top of each other. Instead of comparing the sources, I compared which DataGridView is visible. It worked fine but I still think there's a better way of doing it.

```
    If dgvOrder.Visible = True Then
        ...
    ElseIf dgvProductStock.Visible = True Then
        ...
    End If
```